# Set notify url to paypal payment in my android apps

Tags: android, transactions, paypal, paypal-ipn, notify

Normally on websites, we can set a notify URL to check payment with paypal server. However how do we set it in an app? I am super new to paypal app payment.

I am using MEP.PayPal

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(resultCode) {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        String payKey = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Successful : " + payKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //finish();
        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
        Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //finish();
        break;
    case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
        Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String errorID = 
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
        String errorMessage = 
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //finish();
        break;
    }
}
```

So under Activity.RESULT_OK, I would like to send a post to my notify URL so that the codes in the URL can validate payments.

Also, I get that the paykey can return the transaction details. If so, then I will use it to do the verification instead of using notify url. But after doing much reading, I still could not find the answer to return the transaction details, like maybe data.getStringExtra('transaction_id'), data.getStringExtra('merchant_name'), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this post here [Transaction details from paypal using Pay-key in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789129/transaction-details-from-paypal-using-pay-key-in-android)

I am able to come up with my solution. But I will have to create ASYNC class to make it work.

So it is something like this

```
public class MyPaypalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
String resultExtra;

//some methods you can fill in yourself to integrate with paypal

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(resultCode) {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        String payKey = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        resultExtra = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        new RetreivePaypalData().execute(resultExtra);

        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:

        break;
    case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
        Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String errorID = 
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
        String errorMessage = 
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);

        break;
    }
}

    class RetreivePaypalData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

           private Exception exception;

           protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
               try{

                   HttpPost httppost = null;
                   httppost = new HttpPost("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails");



                   httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", "mybusiness_blalbal.fff.cm");
                   httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", "3243535554");
                   httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE", "AR908E09RG7H0G0GREJ3GH9GHGHDFKGHGIHE99GFDIGHIH34ERGHI");
                   httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", "APP-80W284485P519543T");
                   httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");
                   httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");








                       // Add your data
                       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("payKey", resultExtra));
                       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage", "en_US"));

                       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   HttpResponse response = Client.getInstance().execute(httppost);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                   byte[] data1;
                   data1 = new byte[256];
                   StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                   int len = 0;
                   while (-1 != (len = is.read(data1)) )
                     {
                        buffer.append(new String(data1, 0, len));
                     }
                   Log.e("log_tag",""+buffer.toString());

                   //Make the comparison case-insensitive.
                   is.close();
                   }catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       Log.e("Got Error","error "+ e );
                   }
                   Log.e("Paykey","resultExtra "+ resultExtra );
                   return null;
           }

           protected void onPostExecute(String d) {
               // TODO: check this.exception 
               // TODO: do something with the data
           }
        }
}
```

Just a rough solution. Need to tweak.